# Foundation Orbit Dynamic Load

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation, orbit

Trying to use Orbit inside a page which is loaded with this jQuery plugin:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

All pages loaded with the jQ plugin work fine, and the page with Orbit works fine if it is loaded directly (i.e., opened by itself from the file manager), but when it is loaded inside the main page via the jQ plugin, it is invisible.

Removing `data-orbit` from the `<ul>` tag allows the page to display. What can I do to get Orbit to load? Thanks very much.

Comment: is it `foundation` or `zurb-foundation`?

Comment: `zurb-foundation` since it's related to orbit.